# How to share status of active users in NodeJs if a user logged in different devices?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an android app for the client app and the express for backend server. 
Let's say an authorized user got a token with 8 hrs expiration time. So after 8 hrs, the user would need to log in again. 
My problem is that when an authorized user login in different devices one after another,( like 7:00 AM on the old device and 8:00 AM on new android device), at that time, from a web server, I want to give only 7 hrs expiration token to the new Android device.
To sum up, I want each login users to share the same token to syncing with even if they login multiple devices.

P.S. As this's my first question on SOF, I don't know how to ask good questions properly but I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

I would assign the token along with the date it was created to the user id.

So when the user logs in, you receive an user ID (it could be the email for example) and you reply to the client with the associated info (token and date), of course, in here you need to do some extra checks such as check token expiracy, check if the user id was logged in before (on some other device as you said), but you get the point.

You should keep this information in the database or in some in-memory system such as Redis (depending on the quantity of users the application has).